# CB400 rpm problem

Tags: engine, honda, motorcycle, power, cb400

I have a Honda cb400, its old but still working fine but i’m having problem with its speed. Even if you hit the gas, the rpm is low(can’t tell exact rpm since the gauge is broken). But when i ride her i can only have a maximum of 90kph, even you hit full throttle, it will not accelerate anymore. It will stay in 90kph. Actually, when you try to accelerate even in the lower gear, when she reach the certain rpm, lets say 5000. It will only hit 5000rpm and the speed will not increase. Unless you hit the higher gear.

I’m just a fun of bikes and i have only little knowledge about big bikes, I appreciate your assistance in solving this issue.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What year is the bike?

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that even in neutral the bike won't rev above 5000 rpm? That sounds like it could be a fuel delivery issue.

Comment: Its 1994 model, actually theres a spark plug issue before and i was not able to use for a month. Because of that the carb got clogged and it happened 2 times.  I brought the bike in the shop to clean the carb. I pretty sure it was cleaned. At lower rpm rev sounds ok, problems only occurs during higher rpm. Could it be synchronization issue?